# Multipart/form-data upload file using jQuery ajax clientside only

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, client-side, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload file using ajax without any server-side code, is this possible?

Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/gPcyL/).

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <textarea name="txtComment" id="txtComments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    <div style="padding-top:15px;">
        <label for="photo_file"></label>
        <input data-clear-btn="true" name="photo_file" id="photo_file" data-theme="a" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:15px;">
        <input id="btnSave" data-inline="false" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" onclick="SavePhoto();" value="Save and upload" data-mini="false" type="submit" />
    </div>
    <!-- <a id="btnSave" data-role="button" data-inline="false" href="javascript:void(0);" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" onclick="SavePhoto();" data-mini="false">Save and upload</a>-->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="padding-top:15px;">
        <label for="flip-6"></label>
        <select name="flip" id="flip" data-role="slider">
            <option value="0">Private</option>
            <option value="1">Public</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: AJAX is both client and server side code!

Comment: i cant use serverside code iam using jquery mobile and no grip on serverside and im not using cordova

Comment: Without serverside code you cannot save the image to the server. Only Idea I have is: You could try putting the image in an email attachement to get it across !somehow!.

Comment: thanks for making me clear

Answer (score 0):

AJAX principle is to communicate with server (send / receive), but you cannot write directly a file (security). You must have a PHP (or other language) script on the server to answer the Ajax call, take the datas and write the file.

Comment: is there any serverside javascript framework which can help for example node.js